# Will changing an iCloud profile on iOS harm data on the previous account?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, data-synchronization

I share an iCloud with my mom. If I delete iCloud on my phone, and created a individual one, Will it delete her data?

Comment: you did not delete it, you just signed out. Your mom can keep using it as long she is signed in.

Comment: If you are going to create another icloud account then turn off the synchronization and create your new account using your apple device.

Answer (score 1):

Delete iCloud? You mean sign out I suppose. If you want a separate account without harm of data, Go to **Preferences** > **iCloud** and somewhere there are sync options.

Disable synchronization (possibly other features), sign out of iCloud, then create a new profile and use it on your iPhone. You might need the previous password to continue.